# How to run TCP connection on real android device?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, android-emulator

I'm following [this tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/) for creating an app with server-client chat. It is working like a charm in android emulators as described there. But I want to simulate it on my device. What about port forwarding in real devices?

I've tried connecting my two devices in a single hotspot and sending message. But it is not working. Do I need to change some code for that? or there is other method out there?

Any help will be appreciated!

I'm new to networking and android both.

Server code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

Handler updateConversationHandler;

Thread serverThread = null;

private TextView text;

public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

    updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

    this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    this.serverThread.start();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {

                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;

    private BufferedReader input;

    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

        try {

            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {

                String read = input.readLine();

                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
    private String msg;

    public updateUIThread(String str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
    }
}
}
```

Client code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Socket socket;

private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        String str = et.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        out.println(str);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Any reason for down votes?

Comment: What else I've to try now?

Comment: You should post the code that you're running that doesn't work. We can't debug your code if you don't show it to us.

Comment: @CharlesMcKelvey I've inserted link for that. What is the meaning of posting same code here?

Comment: 1) that's not a link to _your_ code, it's a whole tutorial. 2) Links die all the time which is why the site rules say you need to post your code here in the question.

Comment: Okay I'm posting my server and client code here.

Comment: Also, you need to be much more detailed in describing the exact issue you're facing, not just "it's not working". Do you get errors? Wrong output?

Comment: Exact issue is: Nothing happens on any device when I press `send` button

Comment: @CharlesMcKelvey see the code.

Comment: Are you able to perform a regular ping from the client to the IP address 10.0.2.2?

Comment: how to perform ping in android device? In emulator this is working well.

Comment: I'm sure you can Google for that.

Comment: Yes I can. But I'm sure this is not working because I've set ip and port address to a specific value in both client and server. But it surely be different in any wifi network. Therefore ping will not work. So what should I do for this? @CharlesMcKelvey

Comment: try flushing the client stream after writing to the socket, and can you guarantee that both client and server are in the same network?

Comment: @nandsito can you tell where I should exactly add the code for flushing? and I'm creating hotspot in the device containing server app, and connecting another device with it, which has client app. I've also tried vice versa. But nothing worked. So is this method correct?

Comment: in client's `onClick()` do `out.flush()` after `out.println()`. This method seems alright, but the network must be properly configured prior to running this application

Comment: I have to change IP address for this? or the specified IP is okay? @nandsito

Comment: @14bce109 one would have to inspect your network from inside to tell whether the ip is correct, i can't

Comment: @nandsito okay thank you. Do you have any link to good turorial for this?

Comment: @14bce109 try this http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/how-can-i-see-what-ip-address-my-android-phone-has